# CSS Vertical ul li menu with 2 lines vertical centered

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello have following strange issue, can vertical center the menu text if it's one line, but 2 lines it will messed up my design. In every browser it looks different. It must also be browser compatible.
Someone have an Idea?

here a online version:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vm57C/6/

HTML:

```
<ul id="vert-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Organisatie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feiten en cijfers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Historie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kennis & ontwikkeling</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Maatschappelijk betrokken</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help mee</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Samenwerking in de zorg</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Samen leven, samen werken</a>          
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Samen leven, samen werken</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Catering en horeca</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kunst en cadeaus</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Lenen en spelen</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Maken en doen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Recreatie</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="#">Medezeggenschap</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Publicaties</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* verticaal menu */
#vert-menu {
margin: 0;  
padding: 0; 
}

#vert-menu ul {
margin: 0;  
padding: 0;
list-style:none;
}

#vert-menu > li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 175px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background:#FFF url(../images/vert-menu.jpg) no-repeat;
}


#vert-menu > li > a {
    padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}

#vert-menu > li:hover > a {
    background:#FFF url(../images/vert-menu-active.jpg) no-repeat;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#vert-menu > li > a.active {
    background:#FFF url(../images/vert-menu-active.jpg) no-repeat;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#vert-menu li > .sub-menu {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
#vert-menu li > .sub-menu > li a {
    display:block;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 165px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    color: #83B810;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #83B810;
    text-decoration:none; 
    outline: none;
}

#vert-menu > li > .sub-menu > li:hover > a {
    color: #750D68; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#vert-menu > li > .sub-menu > li > a.active {
    color: #750D68; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for this problem:

http://www.andy-howard.com/verticalAndHorizontalAlignment/index.html

Hope this help you all

Answer (score 2):

Make it appear like a table cell:

```
#vert-menu > li > a {
    padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following modification does what you want:

```
#vert-menu > li > a {
    padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I added `text-align:center`.

But personally I prefer the left aligned version.

Comment: Hello BartVG, I mean vertical centered, my mistake

Comment: verdorie, seems like a hard nut to crack. I've been playing a bit, but I didn't succeed in vertically centering the text. I was thinking of `padding: auto 35px auto 5px`, but it didn't work. Sorry.